# popular solution for display both tiles and vector data in android map app

Tags: vector, android

We are planning to build a location based app like google map in android.

We have some experiences in the PC development,that's to say we have a similar javascript api like google map javascript api, while, we load our own data which are pre-processed to millions of tiles through our original geographic data of arcgis format combined with the template(.mxd) document. We use the same strategy for both the vector data and satellite data.

However We do not think it is a good idea to use the `tile` strategy in mobile platform since it will cause the storage problem. We hope the user can cache the data for offline use.(At least they can cache the vector data(not the tiles but other vector format),since the original satellite data is image which is seem not suitabe to cache).

So we plan to render the vector data using opengl and render the satellite as it is (display the images one by one in an order just like it in the PC).

According to the docs,we should use a sub class of `GLSurfaceView` to use the opengl renderring. But which kind of view can be use for the `images layout` for satellite data? And how to switch betweem them?

I am new in android and I hope someone can give me some advices. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?  Have you looked at the osmdroid project? You can have a tile based background and draw your vector as overlays.

Comment: In fact we are reinventing the wheel but we have to. And we have to build the core engine for the map app ourself. Also,we have the plan to implement the 3d view for the buildings,so create overlays is not a good idea.

Comment: If that is your aim, I fail to understand your question.  What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: create an app like google map, and it should support tile based layer and vector based layer while the vector based layer can display the builds in a 3d view in future.

Comment: @giser, did you all ever create this app?

Comment: It is a hard work, but it seems that I found a proper opensource project at github, check this:https://github.com/opensciencemap/vtm